# Pandas - how to convert RangeIndex into DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series

I have the following dataframe. It is OHLC one-minute data. Obviously I need the T column to become and index in order to use time-series functionallity

C H L O T V

```
13712 6873.0 6873.0 6873.0 6873.0 2018-01-13T17:17:00 799.448421 
13713 6878.0 6878.0 6875.0 6875.0 2018-01-13T17:18:00 1707.578666 
13714 6880.0 6880.0 6825.0 6825.0 2018-01-13T17:21:00 481.245707 
13715 6876.0 6876.0 6876.0 6876.0 2018-01-13T17:22:00 839.177283 
13716 6870.0 6878.0 6830.0 6878.0 2018-01-13T17:23:00 4336.830277
```

I used:

```
df['T'] = pd.to_datetime(df['T'])
```

So far so good! The T column is now recognised as a date

Check:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 13717 entries, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 to 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000013716
Data columns (total 7 columns):
BV    13717 non-null float64
C     13717 non-null float64
H     13717 non-null float64
L     13717 non-null float64
O     13717 non-null float64
T     13717 non-null datetime64[ns]
V     13717 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(6)
memory usage: 857.3 KB
```

And now comes the fun and unexplainable part:

```
df.set_index(df['T'])


   C H L O T V
T

2018-01-03 17:27:00 5710.0 5710.0 5663.0 5667.0 2018-01-03 17:27:00 3863.030204 
2018-01-03 17:28:00 5704.0 5710.0 5663.0 5710.0 2018-01-03 17:28:00 1208.627542 
2018-01-03 17:29:00 5699.0 5699.0 5663.0 5663.0 2018-01-03 17:29:00 1755.123688
```

Still looks good, but when I check the type of index I get:

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=13717, step=1)
```

And now if I try:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

I end up with:

```
DatetimeIndex([          '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004' and so on...
```

which is evidently wrong.

The questions are:
1. Why don't I get the normal DateTimeIndex if I am converting a date to index?

2. How can I convert that RangeIndex to DateTimeIndex with correct timestamps?

Thanks!

Comment: You forget assign back only `df = df.set_index('T')` or use`df.set_index('T', inplace=True)`

Comment: But if use `csv` as input data, simpliest is `df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['T'], index_col=['T'])`

Comment: Input data is json.

But I found out that

df.index = df['T']

does the trick

Comment: OK, then use second solution ;)

Comment: You were right 

df = df.set_index('T')

preserves the dates but converts them to normal index.

Then I have to use 

pd.to_datetime(df.index) 

to get DateTimeIndex

Sorry my first question on StackOverflow. I am finding my way around. Formatting is off (code for example in comment).

Comment: I understand my error now. Without df = df.set_index I was simply converting integers to timestamps adding miliseconds or nanoseconds to initial Unix timestamp.

Comment: exactly, you are right. nanoseconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If input data are `csv` the simpliest is use parameters `parse_dates` and `index_col` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['T'], index_col=['T'])
```

If not, then use your solution, don't forget assign back output of [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and if need drop column `T` also after `DatetimeIndex` use `T` instead `df['T']`:

```
df['T'] = pd.to_datetime('T')
df = df.set_index('T')

#alternative solution
#df.set_index('T', inplace=True)
```

> Why don't I get the normal DateTimeIndex if I am converting a date to index?

Because your index is default (`0,1,2..`), so `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` parse `integers`s like `ns` and get weird datetimes.

Comment: The first solution kept returning RangeIndex. I tried several different parameters permutations. So this did not work for me with the latest pandas 2.1.4


pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['T'], index_col=['T'])

However the second solution does work:
df['T'] = pd.to_datetime('T')

Looks like to_dateset does ensure DateTimeIndex format, while read_csv does not. I could not find in the docs when Pandas uses Index or RangeIndex for datetime formatted input columns.